# Failure Mode : ElasticCache Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

Why am I always getting this error ? using the following code from AutoDiscovery documentation

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/AutoDiscovery.Using.html#AutoDiscovery.Using.ModifyApp.Java

Failure Mode: Redistribute, Hash Algorithm: NATIVE_HASH Max Reconnect Delay: 30, Max Op Timeout: 2500, Op Queue Length: 16384, Op Max Queue Block Time10000, Max Timeout Exception Threshold: 998, Read Buffer Size: 16384, Transcoder: net.spy.memcached.transcoders.SerializingTranscoder@7c417213, Operation Factory: net.spy.memcached.protocol.ascii.AsciiOperationFactory@15761df8 isDaemon: false, Optimized: true, Using Nagle: false, ConnectionFactory: DefaultConnectionFactory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the port was not opened and hence it was not connecting to the Cluster.

Comment: Thanks for posting. You saved lot of time for others.